# pure css drop down expand div background

Tags: html, css

I am creating a pure css drop down using `ul` and `li`, but due to constraints (previous code I cannot change) the nav bar is a `div` and it has some links (`a`) in it.

When I am adding a css drop down, the div expand whenever I am hovering over the `ul` area (as can be seen in my jsfiddle and code). I am trying to figure out if there is a way to present the drop down over the div so it won't expand the div as it is being dropped down.

I tried different positions, and z-index but none of these work. 
My mockup code:

```
<div style="background-color: yellow">
<a herf=#> One </a>
<a herf=#> Two </a>
<a herf=#> Three </a>
<a herf=#> Four </a>
<a herf=#> Five</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">dropdown</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</div>

<style>
ul{
    padding: 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
ul li ul {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kox1b63q/1/

Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/jasonslyvia/kox1b63q/2/

The key point here is understanding `position` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could position the dropdown absolutely:

```
ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
}
```